# Postgresql convert passed parameters into array

Tags: postgresql

Here is the query I want to execute:

```sql
select UNNEST(:vals)
```

where `vals='val1','val1',...`.

The issues with this is that I am getting `ERROR: function unnest(unknown, unknown) does not exist` as `UNNEST` takes an array.
So, is there a way to do it?

I am executing the query using DBeaver

Comment: Are you doing this in `psql` using `\set`? If not in what client? **Add answers as update to question text**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select UNNEST(string_to_array('val,val2,val3',','))
```

but in this case your `:vals` should be `'vall,val2,val3'`

Comment: Thank you @Stepel.
Sure I tried this `select UNNEST(ARRAY[:vals])`
I get this error `ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"`, So, I tried to do this `select UNNEST(ARRAY[(:vars)])`, but PostgreSQL consider all the values in the passed parameter as one string, and the array will have one value. So, this actually does not solve the issue.

Comment: @AliKhaddour please give more details then. How do you pass :vals to the query ? What programming laguage ? Is it pl/pgSQL ?

Comment: @AliKhaddour maybe you need this: `select UNNEST(string_to_array('val,val2,val3',','))` but in this case your :vals should be `'vall,val2,val3'`

Comment: There is no programming laguage, just a plain sql query. In DBeaver I can pass the variable when I execute the query.
For the suggested solution, it is actually a valid solution, but the issue with it is that I need to pass one string that may be so long. I don't know if that would generate a problem later.

Comment: I don't know details of your task but I am not sure if this is the best idea to pass this kind of data to query, especially if it will be really long. Maybe better store those data in another table if you really need use it as rows. All depends what you really need.